# get the selected value from the multiple select option of same class

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have set of the data which I am fetching from the database using loop, here is my view.

```
 @foreach($offer as $off)
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="section-title no-margin-top">{{$off->name}}</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">

                            <ul class="bxslider">
                              <li><img src="{{asset('uploads/offers/'.$off->image)}}" style="padding-left:17%;"></li>
                              <li style="display:none"><img src="{{asset('uploads/offers/46659.jpg')}}"></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <h3 class="no-margin-top">Description</h3>
                            <p style="text-align:justify;">{{$off->description}}</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="e-price">$ <span>{{$off->offerPrice->amount}}</span>.00</div>
                            <div class="row quantity-wrapper form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:7px;">Quantity</label> 
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select class="form-control quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity{{$off->id}}">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                        <option value="9">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-ar btn-block btn-success addtocart" id="{{$off->id}}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
```

Here I am calling the js on clicking the `add To Cart` Button. Currently, I am only being able to get the id of the clicked button. In addition to that, I also want to get the select value of the currently selected dropdown. I am using `js` like this to get the `id` of the clcked button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addtocart').off('click').on('click', function(){
        var offerId = $(this).prop('id');
    });
</script>
```

How can I modify above script in order to get the `value` of the currently selected option along with the `id` of the selected `button`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addtocart').off('click').on('click', function(){
        var offerId = $(this).prop('id');
        var selectedData = $('select[name="quantity"]').val();
        var selectedData = $('#quantity'+offerId).val(); //Optional
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".addtocart").click(function() {
   var getId = $(this).attr("id"); // gets id
   var selectedQty = $("#quantity"+getId).val(); //holds selection of quantity val
});
```

you can use above snippet to achieve your requirement

used `+` to concat string and var `getId`. `.val()` is used to get elements value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#addtocart").click(function(){
    var cart = $('.pr_attribute'); //
    $.each(cart, function(index, value){
        console.log($(value).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back